# How to draw expander (slider) in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a requirement where I need a button which will let the user tap and swipe down/up in order to expand/collapse the control above the button. Something like in this image: [image]

How can I achieve it in xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Template for `Header` and put an image from your question into `HeaderTemplate`. Let me show an example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="FooBorderStyle" >
            <Style.Resources>
                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ABackBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#EF3132" Offset="0.1" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#D62B2B" Offset="0.9" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ABackBrush}"/>
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="titleTemplate">
            <Border Style="{StaticResource FooBorderStyle}" Height="24">
                <Image Source="../Images/yourImage.png" 
                    Margin="4 0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource titleTemplate}"/>
        </Style>

    </Grid.Resources>

    <Expander Name="hcontCtrl" Header="This is the header.">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox>This is a textbox</TextBox>
            <Button>A button</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>

</Grid>
```

Comment: The image is very improper to be used since it would look in contrast to the rest of my page. Is there anything I can do with Path?

Comment: @AshishAgrawal yes, you can. In my view, image is simplier to edit using Microsoft Expression Design or Photoshop or other image tools.

Comment: Okay. I will try my hands on one of those tools maybe. Thanks.